# Getting RESULT_CANCELED for Dialer Intent

Tags: java, android, android-intent, android-dialer

I am trying to get result for dialer Intent using `startActivityForResult()`

Below is my code for Dialer Intent.

```
        button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_DIAL);
            intent.setData(Uri.parse("tel:123456789"));
            startActivityForResult(intent, 1234);
           }
        });

        @Override
        protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, @Nullable Intent data) {
          super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
          if(requestCode == 1234){

           if (resultCode == Activity.RESULT_OK){
             Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "result ok", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
           }else if (resultCode == Activity.RESULT_CANCELED){
               Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Result Cancelled", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
           }
          }

       }
```

whenever I am returning to my activity, Result Cancelled Toast is triggering.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Why do you need the `onActivityResult()` method, can you please explain what are your expected output?

Comment: I need to know whether I called that number using intent. But it simply returning with RESULT_CANCELED result code.

Comment: **"I need to know whether I called that number using intent"**
I don't think you will need `onActivityResult()` to check this. You can check that on your emulator/device. Isn't it?

Comment: Thanks @Saadat, any other way to do this. Also why am I getting RESULT_CANCELED instead of RESULT_OK.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From [doc](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent.html#ACTION_DIAL):

**ACTION_DIAL**

```
public static final String ACTION_DIAL
```

You only have the `ACTION`. If you want to call a number from your application then you just have to put these lines of code into the `onClick()` method and can get what you want:

```
Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_DIAL);
intent.setData(Uri.parse("tel:123456789"));
startActivity(intent); // no need to use startActivityResult(intent,1234)
```

Here, If an **ACTION_DIAL** input is nothing, an empty dialer is started; else `getData()` is URI of a phone number to be dialed or a `tel: <yourURI>` of an explicit phone number.
Additionally, there is no "Output" of `RESULT_OK` or `RESULT_CANCELED`, Cause, the `startActivityResult()` doesn't mean anything to `ACTION_DIAL` but `startActivity(intent)`. Hope it helps.

Answer (score 0):

> why am I getting RESULT_CANCELED instead of RESULT_OK.

`ACTION_DIAL` does not return a result. If you read [the documentation for `ACTION_DIAL`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent.html#ACTION_DIAL), you will see "Output: nothing". Hence, you will usually get `RESULT_CANCELED`. Only activities designed for use with `startActivityForResult()` will return a result code.